# including header file in static html files

Tags: html

I would like to have a separate html file including meta data, link & script tags as well as the visible header in one file which I would then import into my static html pages.

So I have been trying the [w3schools suggested solution](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) however this causes an unpleasant flash when the page loads.

Essentially my static pages start along these lines

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
```

```
function includeHTML() {
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  /*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
    file = elmnt.getAttribute("include-html");
    if (file) {
      /*make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name:*/
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
          if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
          if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
          /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
          elmnt.removeAttribute("include-html");
          includeHTML();
        }
      } 
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      /*exit the function:*/
      return;
    }
  }
}

</script>

<div include-html="staticheader.html"></div>

<body>
```

then include the body of the html and finish like this

```
<div include-html="staticfooter.html"></div>

</body>

<script>
    includeHTML();
</script>

</html>
```

In the staticheader.html are all the tags for meta data, css and js (including bootstrap).  Maybe this is not possible, I assume it is loading the page, getting to the bottom and loading the header and footer and then applying the imports.  No wonder there is millisecond delay before the page formats properly!

I only have about 10 static pages so it is not the end of the world for me to solve the problem by putting the header data back into the individual html files but I am hoping there is a better solution ?

Comment: I think you should check many of the static html generators, or some "server side include" tools. If the page are static, it is better to prepare the static final pages from templates, and keep then static, instead of using javascript etc.  Note: many search engines will not run such code, so you lose keywords, etc

Comment: just install a webserver save to .php and use `include()` function...